# Use a specific column inside the user defined function for summarize function in dplyr

Tags: r, function, dplyr, summarize

I have the following question. I have a dataset *mtcars* and I want to write a a function to summarize the given variable, e.g. *mpg* given that another variable has a particular value, e.g. *vs = 1*. I provide a code, where I want to summarize *mpg* given that *vs = 1* and again summarize given that *am = 1*.

> Error in NextMethod("[") : object 'vs' not found

```
f_1 <- function(data, var){
  
  # Quote the variable that we can use it's name
  var         <- enquo(var)
  
  data %>%
    summarize(p_1          = mean(!!var[vs  == 1], na.rm = TRUE),
              p_2          = mean(!!var[am  == 1], na.rm = TRUE))
}


f_1(data = mtcars, var = mpg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use curly-curly (`{{..}}`) :

```
library(dplyr)

f_1 <- function(data, var){
  data %>%
    summarize(p_1 = mean({{var}}[vs  == 1], na.rm = TRUE),
              p_2 = mean({{var}}[am  == 1], na.rm = TRUE))
}

f_1(data = mtcars, var = mpg)

#      p_1      p_2
#1 24.55714 24.39231
```